# how to change color on SVG with skrollr jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, css, svg

My logo on my website is a SVG.

I have found some javascript, that makes my inline SVG logo editable:

```
/*
     * Replace all SVG images with inline SVG
     */
        jQuery('img.svg').each(function(){
            var $img = jQuery(this);
            var imgID = $img.attr('id');
            var imgClass = $img.attr('class');
            var imgURL = $img.attr('src');

            jQuery.get(imgURL, function(data) {
                // Get the SVG tag, ignore the rest
                var $svg = jQuery(data).find('svg');

                // Add replaced image's ID to the new SVG
                if(typeof imgID !== 'undefined') {
                    $svg = $svg.attr('id', imgID);
                }
                // Add replaced image's classes to the new SVG
                if(typeof imgClass !== 'undefined') {
                    $svg = $svg.attr('class', imgClass+' replaced-svg');
                }

                // Remove any invalid XML tags as per http://validator.w3.org
                $svg = $svg.removeAttr('xmlns:a');

                // Replace image with new SVG
                $img.replaceWith($svg);

            }, 'xml');

        });
```

Now that I can change the color with css, is it then possible to use it with the jQuery plugin skrollr: https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/tree/master/examples, so I can change the color of the logo when scrolling down?

I was trying to add this to SVG but it didn't work: `data-0="fill:rgb(255,0,0);" data-500="fill:rgb(0,0,255);"`

Below is the fiddle for it.

http://jsfiddle.net/NEhmK/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where are you adding the `data-0="fill:rgb(255,0,0);" data-100="fill:rgb(0,0,255);"` attributes? It seems to work for me if I add them to the all the `<path>` elements i.e.

```
<path data-0="fill:rgb(255,0,0);" data-100="fill:rgb(0,0,255);" fill="#6EC5CB"...
```

If you add them elsewhere e.g. the CSS or the `<g>` I don't think the library overrides the fill that already exists on the path.

If you want to add the attributes to the path tag then call `document.rootElement.getElementsByTagName("path")` and loop over the results. E.g.

```
var paths = document.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("path"); 
for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) { 
    paths[i].setAttribute("data-0", "fill:rgb(255,0,0);"); 
    paths[i].setAttribute("data-100", "fill:rgb(0,0,255);"); 
}
```

Or alternately remove all the existing fill attributes from the path.

Comment: I placed the 'data' code in the svg-tag and also tried making a class to place it in, but little did it work.

I have now tried to place inside a path, and you are right it works.

A minor problem though, as you can see I have a lot of paths, so I need to place the 'data' code inside all the <path>-tags?

Is there an easier to get around this?

Comment: Where in the fiddle would you place the code: `var paths = document.rootElement.getElementsByTagName("path"); 
for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) { 
    paths[i].setAttribute("data-0", "fill:rgb(255,0,0);"); 
    paths[i].setAttribute("data-100", "fill:rgb(0,0,255);"); 
}`

Comment: Hmmm, can't seem to get it working.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NEhmK/3/

Comment: I don't know what you've done, but here's your original fiddle modified: http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/Yj5Wh/